# How and when are the raw materials used in the Fabricate spell converted into the item(s)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Fabricate](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Fabricate#content) has a casting time of 10 minutes.

If I was fabricating a pile of wood, feathers and stone into a pile of arrows, is it a pile of material up until the very end of the 10 minutes when it suddenly transforms? Or would it be reasonable to assume it's a continuous process of creation that is generating items, and there would be some completed product, allowing for say an archer under siege to use arrows as they are created.

The closest I can find would be the [Move Earth](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Move%20Earth#content) spell, which creates things over 10 minute increments and definitely creates them continuously. but that has a duration rather than being instantaneous.

RAW seems to make it be immediate "poof" at the end of 10 minutes, which does seem less cool than magical craftsmanship (and less related to the bit about needing proficiency to create high craftsmanship items like weapons).

Answer (score 10):

As you say, RAW it's a spell cast for 10 minutes and then it just happens. For flavor, I'd say it wouldn't be too weird to have it play out as you cast the spell and simply make it so that if you're interrupted before those 10 minutes it all falls apart again, no matter how far along in the progress the spell was. That makes it so that it's technically the same, but is just cooler to imagine.

In the case of arrows from the Fabricate spell being used while the spell is cast, I'd personally rule that none of the arrows are complete until the spell is fully cast (i.e., after 10 minutes) and if taken from the area before that time they fall apart.

Comment: Good perspective! One thing that might be worth adding: how would you deal with someone else (say, the team's Ranger) trying to use one of the completed arrows (firing it) when the spell wasn't yet complete?

Comment: Yeah, added that clarification to my original question. My thought process was if you were under siege, could you supply archers with a continuous stream of arrows while fabricate is going on?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Personally I'd rule that none of the arrows are complete until the spell is fully cast, and if taken from the area before that time they fall apart.

Comment: @Tiny Great idea! As comments don't always last forever (and are sometimes hard to comb through), you might want to include that in your answer.

Comment: @EagerToLearn I could **maybe** be convinced if the person wanting to do it explained how in a very detailed way and that it didn't change the outcome too much. Waiting for the spell to finish could be used to make the encounter/siege more dramatic though, so I'm leaning towards a no ruling from the sounds of it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Tiny, and welcome to the community. @V2Blast thanks for being so welcoming (and all of the useful edits)!

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Thanks! Added it to the answer.

@ EagerToLearn: You're welcome, and thank you. This was a great first experience.